# Getting an account's login details if I am an administrator of a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, login

I work for a business and we have a few staff members registered as admins on the business' Facebook.

However, the person who originally started the Facebook no longer works with us and we need to get the login email/username and password for the page for a newsfeed ad on that we are doing with our mobile website.

We all usually just log in and switch our Facebook accounts over to use as Page, but the ad needs the login and the password which we don't know.

How do I go about getting this information? Who can I contact?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you (or this person) would have contacted the [Facebook Sales Team](https://www.facebook.com/business/contact.php) for the ads. (Unless this is not a Facebook ad).
Maybe you can just repeat the process to get in contact with someone again.

Otherwise, there is no direct way to get in contact with Facebook. You may have to hijack one of the Facebook forms and be sure to state the reasoning there, in the hopes that Facebook Support will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook ad accounts are locked down to user accounts because there are payment card details attached. You should start your own newsfeed ads for now and contact the former employee that had them under their account so they can add you as an admin to the advertising account (yes, it's separate from Facebook Page admin status)

You can direct the person to the [Ad Account Settings Page](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/settings.php) and have them add you as an administrator.